# App working when debugging but not in ad hoc distrubtion

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, avaudiorecorder

I have a very strange bug occurring. I'm monitoring sound levels using AVAudioRecorder and calling an action when the sound peaks over a certain level. It works on the simulator using iOS 6 and on my device connected to Xcode using iOS 7.

When I distribute the app via TestFlight the audio peak method never triggers. When I distribute via ad-hoc and install via iTunes I have the same problem.

Why would it work on my device connected to Xcode but not through an ad-hoc build?

Edit:

I've did some more testing and the problem is definitely related to the microphone. Metering is definitely enabled but the app isn't getting any levels from it. So metering is working when I'm debugging but not ad-hoc.

Comment: So both the testflight and ad-hoc builds are release builds, as opposed to debug builds?

Comment: Are you sure you are distributing the right build?  You may be building your app using one scheme but trying to distribute the wrong build.

Comment: The testflight/adhoc are built under release, testing done under debug. I'm using build & archive to distribute so I don't think there is any way I could be distributing the wrong build.

Comment: I just checked and the target .app I'm distributing is in the Release-iphoneos folder and the Date Modified time matches when I built it. The UI changes I've made also reflect the latest build. It's just the audio detection that isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

> Why would it work on my device connected to Xcode but not through an ad-hoc build?

Sounds like you've failed to include `microphone` among the ["required device capabilities"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3) in your Info.plist:

> **microphone**
>
> Include this key if your app uses the built-in microphone or supports
>   accessories that provide a microphone.

Comment: I thought that might be the problem but I've just added the key and it hasn't fixed anything unfortunately.