# iOS - Can't get sound levels from mic

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, avfoundation

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596949/app-working-when-debugging-but-not-in-ad-hoc-distrubtion) yesterday which didn't get an answer. I've narrowed down the problem to something more specific so I'm asking a new one.

When connected to my Mac and running via Xcode I can get sound levels from the Mic successfully. When the app is run on my device via an adhoc build Mic levels are not being reported.

I've tried everything I can think of with no luck. My guess was some kind of permissions issue which an answer on my previous question alluded to but I added the microphone key to my plist and it hasn't helped.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this on iOS 6 or 7?

Comment: @fzwo the problem is occurring on both. It works fine on both when connected to Xcode but when installed adhoc the mic levels aren't working on either.